# Spring does not want to save the record in the database

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring, spring-boot

**Logs:**

2021-05-09 14:04:19.356 ERROR 22211 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.dzeru.springloginformandoauth2tutorial.repos.PostRepo.save(Object)" because "this.postRepo" is null] with root cause

**My PostMakerController**

```
package com.dzeru.springloginformandoauth2tutorial.controllers;

import com.dzeru.springloginformandoauth2tutorial.entities.Post;
import com.dzeru.springloginformandoauth2tutorial.repos.PostRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class PostMakerController {
    @Autowired
    private PostRepo postRepo;

    public static List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostMapping("/prj")
    public String makePost(String title, String content,
                           Principal principal, Model model) {

        int wordsLength = content.split(" ").length;

        if (title.length() > 30) {
            model.addAttribute("text", "Title size > 30");
        } else if (wordsLength < 30) {
            model.addAttribute("text", "Your content < 30 words");
        } else if (wordsLength > 100) {
            model.addAttribute("text", "Your content > 100 words");
        } else {
            Post post = new Post();
            post.setContent(content);
            post.setAuthor(principal.getName());
            post.setParagraph(title);

            postRepo.save(post);
            posts = postRepo.findAll();

            model.addAttribute("posts", posts);

            return "prj";
        }

        return "prj";
    }
}
```

**My PostRepo**

```
package com.dzeru.springloginformandoauth2tutorial.repos;

import com.dzeru.springloginformandoauth2tutorial.entities.Post;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Repository
public interface PostRepo extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {
}
```

**My form**

```
<form action="/prj" method="post" class="auto_form">
    <div class="container">
        <label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter title" name="title" required>
        </label>
        <label>
            <textarea id="text" cols="100%" rows="20%" placeholder="Enter content" name="content" required></textarea>
        </label>
        <b th:text="${text}"></b>
        <button type="submit" class="button_login">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

No problem, when entering a different logic. Thymeleaf displays everything correctly. Problem on data recording lines in the database: (**PostMakerController**) postRepo.save (post);

**Generates a NullPointerException because id = null. But in my essence the autogenerator for Id is written.**

**My Post entitie**

```
package com.dzeru.springloginformandoauth2tutorial.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String author;
    @NotNull
    private String paragraph;
    @NotNull
    private String content;

    public Post() {
        this("EMPTY", "EMPTY", "EMPTY");
    }

    public Post(@NotNull String author, @NotNull String paragraph, @NotNull String content) {
        this.author = author;
        this.paragraph = paragraph;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Post post = (Post) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, post.id) && Objects.equals(author, post.author) && Objects.equals(paragraph, post.paragraph) && Objects.equals(content, post.content);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, author, paragraph, content);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", author='" + author + '\'' +
                ", paragraph='" + paragraph + '\'' +
                ", content='" + content + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getParagraph() {
        return paragraph;
    }

    public void setParagraph(String paragraph) {
        this.paragraph = paragraph;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

**I`m using MariaDB!**

**Thanks for any help!**

Comment: please post the stacktrace, and show us the exact code that creates NullPointer

Comment: (PostMakerController) postRepo.save(post);

Comment: i still don't see where the null pointer comes from? the save method of jpa will return the saved entity. The entity will never be null.  But anyways try saveAndFlush instead

Comment: It too does't work

Comment: cant help you without a stacktrace (the error message in your console)

Comment: I added in start of question

Comment: you could have saved us a lot of time if u would have posted this from the beginning. You entity is fine. Your Repository bean is null - doesnt get autowired. Check your component scan - it probably doesnt read it. And also remove `@Service` from your PostRepo that is jsut wrong you only use `@Repository`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed. Problem was in:  Data truncation: Data too long for column 'column_name'.
I just make: jdbcCompliantTruncation=false in my application.properties